# Column Whitespace

Tags: tables

I am using the below table and I am getting A LOT of white space between my first column and my models. The space between my models is fine.

```
\begin{table}\caption{Regression table\label{tab1}}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l r l r l r l}
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 1}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 2}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 3}\\
\hline
\hline
Variable 1 & 12.758 & * &  13.822 & *** & 2.123 & *\\
\hline
\textit{*p < 0.05, ** p < 0.01, *** p < 0.001}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

How can I trim this down so I do not need to use landscape?

Comment: Use `\multicolum{4}{l}{...}` for the last line

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @percusse There was an error in my code. I don't see the extra separator

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the response. There was an error in my code, but I do not know what you mean by last line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The excessive width of the first column arises because the final line of the `tabular` environment, `\textit{*p < 0.05, ** p < 0.01, *** p < 0.001}`, is interpreted as belonging to the first column. Use something like `\multicolumn{7}{l}{<Content>}` instead. (In your initial example, you had 5 columns of data but only 4 columns were specified in the setup of the `tabular` environment. I see you've updated the code in the meantime to feature 7 columns.)

Separately, I would recommend using the `booktabs` package to get some good-looking horizontal rules (produced by `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\cmidrule`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Regression table}\label{tab1}
\centering

\smallskip
\begin{tabular}{@{}l cccccc @{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 1}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 2}
& \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Model 3}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-7}
& Coef. & SE & Coef. & SE & Coef. & SE\\
\midrule
Variable 1 & 12.758 & * &  13.822 & *** & 2.123 & *\\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{* $p < 0.05$, ** $p < 0.01$, *** $p < 0.001$.}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is almost exactly what I wanted. How can I get the caption to center across the entire table and not have the preamble "Table 1:".

Comment: @CJ12 - I guess you don't need a "caption" -- in the LaTeX-specific sense of the word -- for your table. Just insert the instruction `\multicolumn{7}{c}{Regression table}\\` after `\begin{tabular}{@{} l cccccc @{}}`, and replace `\toprule` with `\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]`. Oh, and you can also omit the `\smallskip` statement.

Comment: the only problem is my header is several lines stacked and with caption it worked but with this new method is it possible to stack the header? If I want Regression table and under it 'Attempt B'

Comment: @CJ12: To "stack" (and center-set, right?) two consecutive header lines using the `\multicolumn` method, you might write `\multicolumn{7}{c}{Regression table}` `\\ ` `\multicolumn{7}{c}{Attempt B}` `\\ `