# Adapting Thesis frontispiece

Tags: thesis, front-matter, frontespizio

I am learning LateX for my thesis work and I have already realized a frontispece for that using the following code:

```
%%%% Frontespizio Tesi



\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[swapnames]{frontespizio}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontespizio}
%\begin{Preambolo*}
%\usepackage{fourier}
%\newcommand{\VOF}{\textsc{vof}}
%\end{Preambolo*}
\Universita{della Campania Luigi Vanvitelli

SCUOLA POLITECNICA E DELLE SCIENZE DI BASE}
\Logo[2cm]{Logo-Uni-Vanvitelli.png}
\Dipartimento{Ingegneria Civile Industiale e dell'Informazione \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt} \par Ingegneria dell'Informazione}
\Corso[Laurea Magistrale]{Ingegneria Informatica}
\Titoletto{Tesi di laurea Magistrale}
\Titolo{Object Tracking and Detection
}\
\Candidato[A18000132]{Michele~Belladonna}
\Relatore{Ch.mo Prof.~Palmieri Francesco A.N.}
%\NRelatore{Coordinatore}{}
%\Correlatore{Ch.mo Prof.~Adalberto Orsatti}
%\NCorrelatore{Supervisore della ricerca}{}
\Annoaccademico{2017-2018}
\end{frontespizio}
...
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: my frontispiece]

Actually, as suggested by my University, I would like something like that:

[image: frontispiece unicampania]

Is that feasible? How could I make it?
Thanks.

Comment: Not with frontespizio, sorry.

Comment: Well. You mean I should use titlepage environment? The problem is that I would have no idea how to start.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280 and https://github.com/johannesbottcher/titlepageExamples/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare the following file `frontispiece.tex` and compile it with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Adjust the lengths as desired.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  top=2cm,
  left=5cm,
  right=2cm,
  bottom=2cm,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\baskerville}{Baskervaldx}
\newfontfamily{\titillium}{DejaVu Sans} % what's Titillium?

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\baskerville
\raggedright

\makebox[\textwidth][s]{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \includegraphics[height=2cm,width=2cm,valign=t]{example-image}%
  }
  \small
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
  Universit\`a\\
  degli Studi\\
  della Campania\\
  \itshape Luigi Vanvitelli
  \end{tabular}\hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
  Scuola Politecnica\\
  e delle Scienze di Base
  \end{tabular}\qquad
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
  Dipartimento di Ingegneria\\
  Industriale e dell'Informazione\\
  Ingegneria dell'Informazione
  \end{tabular}%
}

\vspace{\stretch{1}}

{\fontsize{14}{24}\itshape Corso di Laurea Magistrale in\par}

{\fontsize{18}{24}\bfseries Ingegneria Informatica\par}

\vspace{2cm}

{\fontsize{14}{24}\bfseries\titillium Tesi di Laurea in Xyz\par}
{\fontsize{23}{32}\titillium Object Tracking and Detection\par}

\vspace{\stretch{2}}

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
Candidato\\
\itshape Nome Cognome
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
Relatore\\
\itshape Nome Cognome
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
Correlatore\\
\itshape Nome Cognome
\end{tabular}\hfill
A. A. 2017/2018

\end{document}
```

Then you can include the PDF in your thesis with `\includepdf` of the package `pdfpages`.

[image]

Comment: @michele_ub Been there, done that. `;-)` In bocca al lupo!

Comment: Just a question: what's the menaning of {@{}l@{}} in tabular environment? Can you suggest a good reference for that? (Crepi!)

Comment: I think this removes white space at the beginning and end of a cell.

Comment: It's also used here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102960 Maybe you can play with the example. For more information, I would recommend reading a dedicated recent LaTeX book ar script.

Comment: Would you say this is a dupe of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280?

Comment: Not sure about it.